# Error occured when tried to build in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-build

"Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart."
This error occured when I tried to run build runner in flutter.

Comment: Did you try to create a new project that makes sure the environment is correct without any problem? Did you also see some error messages from the editor? Did you build it scuessfully before?

Comment: Yes I have built it successfully before.The error occurred when I added injectable_generator in dev dependencies.